# Trying to get file_name from codeigniter after uploading

Tags: php, codeigniter, upload

What I am trying to do is after uploading the file parse the cvs file to the screen with print_r so I can do some things with it. I cannot seem to figure out how you access the file name with the $data. I have tried several things like $file_name, $data['file_name], and $this->data->$file_name. The relevant part is on line 37.

Not sure what I am doing wrong. I have looked at the code igniter documentation for the uploader library but it doesn't be sufficient to answer my question. Thanks for any help!

```
<?php

class Upload extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
    }

    function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('upload_form', array('error' => ' ' ));
    }

    function do_upload()
    {
        $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'csv';
        $config['max_size'] = '100';
        $config['max_width']  = '1024';
        $config['max_height']  = '768';

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        $this->load->library('getcsv');

        if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
        {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

            $this->load->view('upload_form', $error);
        }
        else
        {
            $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
            $this->load->view('upload_success', $data);
                echo 'The file name is: '.$file_name;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: What happens when you do var_dump($data) before you load the view?

Comment: You could simply change this line -> $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data()); to $data = $this->upload->data(); and then to access the name $data['file_name'];

Answer (score 3):

The filename can be anything you want. This is clearly in the documentation, you might've been reading the wrong page or something:

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html

```
file_name: If set CodeIgniter will rename the uploaded file to this name. The extension provided in the file name must also be an allowed file type.
```

OR:

You can get it from $this->upload->data(), which is an array.

```
$this->upload->data()

This is a helper function that returns an array containing all of the data related to the file you uploaded. Here is the array prototype:

Array
(
    [file_name]    => mypic.jpg
    [file_type]    => image/jpeg
    [file_path]    => /path/to/your/upload/
    [full_path]    => /path/to/your/upload/jpg.jpg
    [raw_name]     => mypic
    [orig_name]    => mypic.jpg
    [client_name]  => mypic.jpg
    [file_ext]     => .jpg
    [file_size]    => 22.2
    [is_image]     => 1
    [image_width]  => 800
    [image_height] => 600
    [image_type]   => jpeg
    [image_size_str] => width="800" height="200"
)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Use the following code :**

```
if($this->upload->do_upload($file)){
 //Get uploaded file data here
 $allData=$this->upload->data();
 $myFile = $allData['file_name'];
}
```